# Is there a function calculating derivative of digamma function?

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, gamma-function

I want to calculate the derivative of digamma function in R.

R has an existing function called `digamma`, but I cannot find a function for the derivative of digamma function. Is it possible to write code for differentiated digamma function in R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it is called `trigamma`

```
q <- trigamma(3)
```

There is also `psigamma`: psigamma(x, deriv) (deriv >= 0) computes the deriv-th derivative of ψ(x).